# Running Specific TestNG Suites with Maven via command line

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I am trying to run specific TestNG suites in Maven using the command line.

I have two different suites
`smoke.xml`
`regression.xml`

My `pom.xml` file looks like this

```
<groupId>com.FNB</groupId>
<artifactId>FNB_Testing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>FNB_Testing</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>/FNB_Testing/regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>/FNB_Testing/smoke.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using the command `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=*suite name*`

However it will only ever run the regression suite even if somke.xml is used

Comment: did you find below answer useful? did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can parameterize multiple suite files like below

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
 <!-- Pass testng.xml files as argument from command line -->
    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Then execute the following command to parametrize multiple testng.xml files using Maven:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=regression.xml,smoke.xml
```

Comment: * `-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=regression.xml,smoke.xml`